# Authenticating with Google Cloud from Apache Beam application via code

Tags: apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I'm trying to run an Apache Beam application in [Kinesis Data Analytics](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/data-analytics/) which uses Apache Flink as the runtime. The pipeline uses the [PubsubIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.28.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubIO.html) connector. I'm trying to [authenticate with Google Cloud using code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code), since Kinesis Data Analytics does not allow to export environment variables, exporting [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started) environment variable doesn't seem to be an option.

I'm trying to authenticate using code as below.

```
    GoogleCredentials credential = GoogleCredentials
            .fromStream(credentialJsonInputStream)
            .createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub");
    credential.refreshIfExpired();

    options.setGcpCredential(credential);
```

The options reference here inherits [PubsubOptions](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.28.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubOptions.html).

But when running the application it fails with the exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline$PipelineExecutionException:
> com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403
> Forbidden POST
> https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/topics/my-topic:publish
> {   "code" : 403,   "errors" : [ {
> "domain" : "global",
> "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",
> "reason" : "forbidden"   } ],   "message" : "The request is missing a valid API key.",   "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED" }     at
> org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:371)
> at
> org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner$DirectPipelineResult.waitUntilFinish(DirectRunner.java:339)
> at
> org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:219)
> at
> org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.run(DirectRunner.java:67)
> at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:322)  at
> org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:308)   at
> com.amazonaws.kinesisanalytics.beam.BasicBeamStreamingJob.main(BasicBeamStreamingJob.java:67)

While debugging I noticed that the `PubsubOptions` reference passed to the [org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.PubsubJsonClient.PubsubJsonClientFactory#newClient](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/af59192ac95a564ca3d29b6385a6d1448f5a407d/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubJsonClient.java#L82) returns `null` when calling `GcpOptions#getGcpCredential`

I'd really appreciate any insights on how to authenticate in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

[GcpOptions#setGcpCredential](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/gcp/options/GcpOptions.html#setGcpCredential-com.google.auth.Credentials-) option can’t be used with Flink runner, because the Flink runner serializes PipelineOptions, but the [getGcpCredential](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/gcp/options/GcpOptions.html#getGcpCredential--) is annotated with @JsonIgnore.

When no credential has been set explicitly via [GcpOptions#setGcpCredential](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/gcp/options/GcpOptions.html#setGcpCredential-com.google.auth.Credentials-),
GCP services such as Pub/Sub uses a credential based upon the currently set [GcpOptions#credentialFactoryClass](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/gcp/options/GcpOptions.html#setCredentialFactoryClass-java.lang.Class-).

So instead of calling `options.setGcpCredential(credential)`, we can define a custom `GcpCredentialFactory` class. Then pass it to `GcpOptions#credentialFactoryClass`

```
options.setCredentialFactoryClass(CustomGcpCredentialFactory.class);
```

Your application's `PipelineOptions` interface would need to extend the `GcpOptions` interface, for you to be able to call the above method on your `options` reference.

```java
public class CustomCredentialFactory extends GcpCredentialFactory {

  private static CustomCredentialFactory INSTANCE = new CustomCredentialFactory();

  private CustomCredentialFactory(PipelineOptions o) {  }

  /**
   * Required by GcpOptions.GcpUserCredentialsFactory#create(org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
   */
  public static CustomCredentialFactory fromOptions(PipelineOptions o) {

      return new CustomCredentialFactory(o);
   }

  @Override
  public Credentials getCredential() {

      try {

          // Load the GCP credential file (from S3, Jar, ..)
          InputStream credentialFileInputStream = SomeUtil.getCredentialInputStream();

          return GoogleCredentials
                  .fromStream(credentialFileInputStream)
                  .createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub");

      } catch (IOException e) {
          return null;
      }
  }
}
```